# Is increased movement speed required for higher difficulty levels?

Tags: diablo-iii

Boots have increased movement speed on them as one of their possible affixes, and there are also a few skills that increase movement speed.  Does this become more important in later difficulties, especially when elites have three or four abilities that drop area effects everywhere?

More importantly, is it possible to survive Inferno without any increased movement speed at all, whether playing a melee or ranged class?

Comment: Definitely possible, but movement speed is always helpful depending on enemies skills, and even own build.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not required in the same sense that most stats aren't required. It's definitely one of the more beneficial stats if you have trouble kiting or getting out of the way of some attacks.

It's definitely possible to survive without it, but you may beat your head against a wall more than once.

The main benefit of movement speed comes from possibly being able to kite the faster mobs, and helping you out with late reaction speed or latency in terms of dodging attacks.

Comment: I agree - it's not required.  I've played Inferno acts 1 and 2 with and without movement speed - it's nice to have, but not at all necessary. (I play Monk)

Answer (score 1):

On my witch doctor, I feel increased movement speed is needed to kite and help compliment my crowd control abilities.